# twitter API rate limit

Tags: r, twitter, cron, twitter-oauth

I want to collect data from twitter over a period of several weeks.

To do so, I use RStudio Server and crontab to automatically run several scripts like the following:

```
require(ROAuth)
require(twitteR)
require(plyr)

load("twitter_authentication.Rdata")
registerTwitterOAuth(cred)

searchResults <- searchTwitter("#hashtag", n=15000, since = as.character(Sys.Date()-1), until = as.character(Sys.Date()))
head(searchResults)

tweetsDf = ldply(searchResults, function(t) t$toDataFrame())
write.csv(tweetsDf, file = paste("tweets_test_", Sys.Date() - 1, ".csv", sep = ""))
```

On some days, I will only have a few tweets (up to 100) per hashtag and so the script runs smoothly. However, on other days there will be thousands of tweets for a certain hashtag (of course I am not using the term "hashtag" but the term I need for my study).

I can add `retryOnRateLimit=10` to `serchTwitter`. But when I search for multiple hashtags every day, how should I time these queries in crontab?

In order to organize these queries, I need to know how many tweets I am able to collect by running the script once within the 15 minute time interval! Does anybody know the answer? (of course, according to the Twitter API rate limits, I can do

> 180 queries per 15 minute window

but how many tweets is this?)

Comment: I just tried to collect yesterday's tweets, which mentioned @WhiteHouse. After more than 11,000 tweets, I reached the rate limit.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than performing a search every few minutes, you should use the **[Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters)**

This will deliver you a real-time feed of all the data flowing through Twitter. You can set a filter for your search term.

There's no "rate limit" as such - you just make a single persistent connection and Twitter deliver a sample of all the tweets matching your search term.

Comment: Ok, but when I want to collect data over a period of 4 months, including several hashtags, isn't that a problem when I have a single persistent connection? That means that I am not able to use RStudio Server for four months!

Comment: No, that's not a problem. Set up a server, give it unique Twitter API keys, then start monitoring and dumping the results into your database.

Comment: can someone provide a code example to this solution?