# How to solve rate limit exceed for Twitter API

Tags: ruby, twitter

Really appreciate your help in advance. I'm working on an application which lets users share their own home timeline with each other realtime. So I need to use Twitter API, but it occurs error `Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests: Rate limit exceeded`.

My purpose is to get each user's timeline in real-time. But it's limited by Twitter.

I have 2 options.

1) Get recent 100 tweets per 15 minutes
I wish I may get these volumes. But be a little worried whether the case using application-only authentication includes mine or not.

2) Pay to Twitter
Does Twitter allow me to use over limitation if I paid? And how?

schedule.rb

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/environment")
set :environment, Rails.env.to_sym
set :output, "#{Rails.root.to_s}/log/cron.log"

every 1.minutes do
  begin
    rake "share:twitter"
  rescue => e
    raise e
  end
end
```

lib/tasks/share.rake

```
namespace :share do
  task :twitter => :environment do
    share_twitter = ShareTwitter.new
    share_twitter.share
  end
end
```

lib/share_twitter.rb

```
class ShareTwitter
  def share
    @users = User.all

    @users.each do |user|
      @client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
        config.consumer_key        = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:twitter][:consumer_id]
        config.consumer_secret     = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:twitter][:consumer_secret]
        config.access_token        = user.token
        config.access_token_secret = user.secret
     end

      @timeline = @client.home_timeline(max_id: max_id,count: 100)
      @timeline.save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: A quick search shows info on paid API access [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/pricing.html) - hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your information

Comment: You also might look at the posts under "Related" on the right, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151307/twitter-api-rate-limit?rq=1) which talks about the Streaming API and seems to do what you're looking for.

Comment: @BobRodes Streaming API has not been working.

Comment: All right. In any case, there are several other posts listed there.